# PyQt keyboard and more fields

Tags: python, qt, keyboard, widget, pyqt

I have a PyQt widget (on which I have a numeric keyboard and two input fields). I would like to edit both input fields with this numeric keyboard. How can I move between the input fields?

My sample code:

```
class Form1(QWidget):
    showForm1Signal = pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Form1, self).__init__(parent)

        self.styleFirstText = QtGui.QLabel("First:", self)
        self.styleFirstText.move(20,20)
        self.styleFirstText.resize(100,20)

        self.styleFirstField = QtGui.QLineEdit(self)
        self.styleFirstField.move(100,20)
        self.styleFirstField.resize(100,20)

        self.styleSecondText = QtGui.QLabel("Second:", self)
        self.styleSecondText.move(20,60)
        self.styleSecondText.resize(100,20)

        self.styleSecondField = QtGui.QLineEdit(self)
        self.styleSecondField.move(100,60)
        self.styleSecondField.resize(100,20)

        self.zero = QtGui.QPushButton("0",self)
        self.zero.move(0,740)
        self.zero.resize(160,60)

        self.one = QtGui.QPushButton("1",self)
        self.one.move(0,680)
        self.one.resize(160,60)

        self.two = QtGui.QPushButton("2",self)
        self.two.move(160,680)
        self.two.resize(160,60)

        self.three = QtGui.QPushButton("3",self)
        self.three.move(320,680)
        self.three.resize(160,60)

        self.four = QtGui.QPushButton("4",self)
        self.four.move(0,620)
        self.four.resize(160,60)

        self.five = QtGui.QPushButton("5",self)
        self.five.move(160,620)
        self.five.resize(160,60)

        self.six = QtGui.QPushButton("6",self)
        self.six.move(320,620)
        self.six.resize(160,60)

        self.seven = QtGui.QPushButton("7",self)
        self.seven.move(0,560)
        self.seven.resize(160,60)

        self.eight = QtGui.QPushButton("8",self)
        self.eight.move(160,560)
        self.eight.resize(160,60)

        self.nine = QtGui.QPushButton("9",self)
        self.nine.move(320,560)
        self.nine.resize(160,60)

        self.back_button = QtGui.QPushButton("DELETE",self)
        self.back_button.move(160,740)
        self.back_button.resize(320,60)
        self.back_button.setStyleSheet(style14)
        self.back_button.clicked.connect(self.back)

        nums = [self.zero,self.one,self.two,self.three,self.four,self.five,self.six,self.seven,self.eight,self.nine]

        for i in nums:
            i.setStyleSheet(style)
            i.clicked.connect(self.nums)

    def nums(self):
        global num
        global newNum
        global opVar

        sender = self.sender()

        newNum = int(sender.text())
        setNum = str(newNum)

        if opVar == False:
            self.styleFirstField.setText(self.styleFirstField.text() + setNum)

        else:
            self.styleFirstField.setText(setNum)
            opVar = False

    def pointClicked(self):
        global opVar

        if "." not in self.styleFirstField.text():
            self.styleFirstField.setText(self.styleFirstField.text() + ".")          

    def back(self):
        self.styleCashRegisterReceipt.backspace()
```

Comment: What do you mean by "move between"?  Like switch focus?

Comment: Yes. I like switch focus.

Comment: My opinion: Maybe I should use self.styleFirstField.selectionChanged.connect() and self.styleSecondField.selectionChanged.connect() But I don't know how. :-(